# angular routing on ios9 $rootScope:infdig error

Tags: angularjs, webview, ios9

Routing in angular app that worked in ios8, produces a [$rootScope:infdig] error in ios9. I have tried both `ngRoute` and `ui.router` but the result is the same.

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
```

Any solution to this?

Comment: Found this link open radar [https://openradar.appspot.com/22186109](https://openradar.appspot.com/22186109) so there doesn't seem to be a fix yet.

Comment: Another link on issue on angular github [https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12241](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12241) again no solution as yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though this is marked as a duplicate of this question. This is the best way to resolve this issue.

[ionic app iOS 9 problems [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32632888/ionic-app-ios-9-problems-rootscopeinfdig-10-digest-iterations-reached)

The selected answer in this post directs you over to this plugin which patches all the iOS9 issues with angular.
https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c

This Patch works for `Angular 1.2.0 – 1.4.5` and **all newer versions of angular will have this fix embedded.**

Answer (score 1):

This answer from [Clever Coder](https://github.com/CleverCoder) on [angular issue 12241](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12241) based on Angular v1.4.3

```
diff --git a/src/ng/browser.js b/src/ng/browser.js
index 928de95..3b9957e 100644
--- a/src/ng/browser.js
+++ b/src/ng/browser.js
@@ -87,7 +87,9 @@ function Browser(window, document, $log, $sniffer) {
   var cachedState, lastHistoryState,
       lastBrowserUrl = location.href,
       baseElement = document.find('base'),
-      reloadLocation = null;
+      reloadLocation = null,
+      pendingHref = null,
+      pendingHrefTimer = null;

   cacheState();
   lastHistoryState = cachedState;
@@ -124,6 +126,18 @@ function Browser(window, document, $log, $sniffer) {
     if (location !== window.location) location = window.location;
     if (history !== window.history) history = window.history;

+    // Schedule cleaning up pendingHref on the next run loop for setting URL. This is to handle
+    // the case where the browser doesn't update the location.* properties immediately
+    if (!pendingHrefTimer && pendingHref && url) {
+      pendingHrefTimer = setTimeout(function () {
+        if (location.href == pendingHref) {
+          console.log('Actual href updated... setting pendingHref to null from setTimeout');
+          pendingHref = null;
+        }
+        pendingHrefTimer = null;
+      }, 0);
+    }
+
     // setter
     if (url) {
       var sameState = lastHistoryState === state;
@@ -147,6 +161,7 @@ function Browser(window, document, $log, $sniffer) {
         // Do the assignment again so that those two variables are referentially identical.
         lastHistoryState = cachedState;
       } else {
+        pendingHref = url;
         if (!sameBase || reloadLocation) {
           reloadLocation = url;
         }
@@ -161,10 +176,22 @@ function Browser(window, document, $log, $sniffer) {
       return self;
     // getter
     } else {
+      var href = location.href.replace(/%27/g, "'");
+      if (pendingHref) {
+        //console.log('.. using pendingHref for url() return value');
+        href = pendingHref;
+      }
+
+      if (location.href == pendingHref) {
+        console.log('Actual href updated... setting pendingHref to null in getter');
+        pendingHref = null;
+      }
+
+      //var href = location.href.replace(/%27/g,"'");
       // - reloadLocation is needed as browsers don't allow to read out
       //   the new location.href if a reload happened.
       // - the replacement is a workaround for https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=407172
-      return reloadLocation || location.href.replace(/%27/g,"'");
+      return reloadLocation || href;
     }
   };
```

Apparently resolves the issue, but not in other versions of Angular.