# ionic app iOS 9 problems [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, ios9

in my ionic/angularjs application I get some errors on iOS 9 on the filtering mechanism if I click on a ionic list card item.

The error I get:

Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []

And the callstack:
[image: Callstack]

It only happens if I click on a entry or if I click back from that entry. On iOS8 everything works fine.

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12241

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well I found out that this is a common bug in iOS9 and there's a patch for this:

https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c

With this patch everything works again.